# Upper bound of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose that $\left|a_n-b_n\right| \leq \lambda_n\left|a_{n-1}-b_{n-1}\right|$ for all $n$ with $\lambda_n < 1.$ Find an upper bound on $\left|a_n-b_n\right|$ in terms of $\left|a_0-b_0\right|$ and $\lambda= \max \{\ \lambda_i : 1 \leq i \leq n \}$.

I can't think of anything and not even sure where to start. Some help would be great.

Comment: Hint: $\displaystyle |a_{n-1}-b_{n-1}|\le \lambda_n|a_{n-2}-b_{n-2}$. Can you continue?

Comment: @Galc127 I'm not totally sure how is that going to help. Could you explain, please?

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Show by induction on $n$ that

$$|a_n-b_n|\le|a_0-b_0|\prod_{k=1}^n\lambda_k\;.$$

Then get a simple upper bound on the product.

Comment: One could say that $|a_n-b_n|\leq \lambda^n|a_0-b_0|$?